# What are Foil Trading Cards?

Tags: steam-trading-cards

In the Steam Marketplace, I've noticed some trading cards called "Foil Trading Cards". I can see from the price difference between an original and foil card that foil cards are much more valuable, but *do foil cards actually do anything different than regular cards?*

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Steam Foil Trading cards can be crafted into foil badges, similar to how you can craft normal badges from normal trading cards. Other than that, it is useless, but everyone thinks they need one. They are essentially rarer trading cards. They are found the same way normal trading cards are.

From the [Trading Cards FAQ:](http://steamcommunity.com/tradingcards/faq)

> **What are Foil Trading Cards?**
>   There is a small chance whenever you get a Trading Card from playing a game that it will have a special foil border. You'll need to collect a set of foil cards in order to craft them into a foil badge. There is no extra benefit to having foil cards or foil badges aside from their rarity.

Comment: Do you know if foil badges are worth more experience?  Sounds like no, but I'd like confirmation.

Comment: @ScottBeeson, I bet you'll get an answer if you post your question in a new page.

Comment: They are not worth more experience (at least in one case): http://imgur.com/O7XglRo

Comment: The only advantage to doing them would be to get the extra EXP earned for completing a Badge (if you had no other Badges to do, seeing that many are pretty easy (like CS:GO's Badges)), and the different looking Badge to put on display. Foil's also only have one level max instead of the normal five.